# Design of popup window when clicked on account (rwd theme)

Tags: rwd-theme

I am trying to customize the rwd theme. When you click on the account button above on the right side of the header, a popup window appears. My question is which file contains the css rules for the popup window. I searched but I didn't find the right file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RWD theme account drop-down box is achieved through using custom jQuery in `skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js`.

You can find the `<CSS>` in `skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles.css`

[image]

You can use Firebug or Google Chrome Element Inspector to see from which file the `<CSS>` is loaded and what lines to look for.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for :-), now I can try to implement my idea^^